# osx python setup.py will not install xattr-0.6.1 application

Tags: python, macos, svn, installation

I'm new to svn and python, but I really want to use a more recent version of xattr that includes more useful features than the original that came with the OS.

On OSX 10.5.6, I'm having trouble installing xattr-0.6.1.

From the local machine in Terminal:

```
$ svn co http://svn.red-bean.com/bob/xattr/releases/xattr-0.6.1/
```

The files are downloaded and placed in ~/xattr-0.6.1/

```
$ cd xattr-0.6.1/
$ sudo python setup.py install

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
This script requires setuptools version 0.6c11 to run (even to display
help).  I will attempt to download it for you (from
http://pypi.python.org/packages/2.5/s/setuptools/), but
you may need to enable firewall access for this script first.
I will start the download in 15 seconds.

(Note: if this machine does not have network access, please obtain the file

   http://pypi.python.org/packages/2.5/s/setuptools/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg

and place it in this directory before rerunning this script.)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/2.5/s/setuptools/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
creating xattr.egg-info
writing xattr.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to xattr.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to xattr.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing entry points to xattr.egg-info/entry_points.txt
writing manifest file 'xattr.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'xattr.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.macosx-10.5-i386/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.macosx-10.5-i386-2.5
creating build/lib.macosx-10.5-i386-2.5/xattr
copying xattr/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-i386-2.5/xattr
copying xattr/constants.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-i386-2.5/xattr
copying xattr/tool.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-i386-2.5/xattr
running build_ext
building 'xattr._xattr' extension
creating build/temp.macosx-10.5-i386-2.5
creating build/temp.macosx-10.5-i386-2.5/xattr
gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -Wno-long-double -no-cpp-precomp -mno-fused-madd -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DMACOSX -I/usr/include/ffi -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch ppc -pipe -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/include/python2.5 -c xattr/_xattr.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.5-i386-2.5/xattr/_xattr.o
unable to execute gcc: No such file or directory
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

To check the version of python:

```
$ python -V
Python 2.5.1
```

It appears to have installed the python update.

I try to run the xattr install again:

```
$ sudo python setup.py install
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing xattr.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to xattr.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to xattr.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing entry points to xattr.egg-info/entry_points.txt
writing manifest file 'xattr.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.macosx-10.5-i386/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'xattr._xattr' extension
gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -Wno-long-double -no-cpp-precomp -mno-fused-madd -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DMACOSX -I/usr/include/ffi -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch ppc -pipe -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/include/python2.5 -c xattr/_xattr.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.5-i386-2.5/xattr/_xattr.o
unable to execute gcc: No such file or directory
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Am I missing an important fundamental element or is there something wrong with the setup.py configuration, or perhaps something else I may have overlooked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs to compile a C file, so it needs `gcc`. Mac folks need to install [XCode](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/whats-new.html). **Update** As @jathanism mentions, you should have an XCode install DVD that came with your Mac (most likely version 3.2).

For example:

```
atlas% which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
atlas% gcc -v
Target: i686-apple-darwin10
..
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)
```

Comment: That link is to XCode 4, which you have to buy. A version of XCode appropriate to your system revision comes bundled on your installation DVD in the "Optional Installs" directory.

Comment: Thank you kindly sirs @samplebias, @jathanism. Turns out my 10.5 Leotard Upgrade disk had Xcode 3.0, which included gcc 4.0. After the install of Xcode I was able to run the setup.py and the updated version of xattr is now installed. :)

Comment: Glad to hear you're up and running!